# Count repeated combinations in Matlab

Tags: matlab, match, cell

Let us consider the following situation, for instance we have cell-matrix A:

```
A:
 A(:,1)A(:,2) A(:,3)   A(:,4)    A(:,5)        
'CM'  '00118''000151' '19970303''19970729'
'RO'  '01356''043605' '19970212''19970401' 
'CM'  '01464''000151' '19970121''19970218'
'RO'  '01356''043605' '19970119''19970313' 
'CM'  '00118''043605' '19970114''19970219' 
'CM'  '00118''000151' '19970523''19970728'
```

In the first three columns, both strings and values are combined and repeated along the matrix.

I would liketo create a new column,

```
REP = num2cell(REP);
A(:,end+1) = REP;
```

that will correspond to the number of repetitions of A(:,3) for each matching A(:,1). For instance the output for this example would be:

```
Output for A:
A(:,1) A(:,2) A(:,3)   A(:,4)    A(:,5)   REP        
'CM'  '00118''000151' '19970303''19970729''3'
'RO'  '01356''043605' '19970212''19970401''2'   
'CM'  '01464''000151' '19970121''19970218''3' 
'RO'  '01356''043605' '19970119''19970313''2' 
'CM'  '00118''043605' '19970114''19970219''1' 
'CM'  '00118''000151' '19970523''19970728''3'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of the two columns, use [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to transform strings into unique numeric labels. Then count repetitions for each combination of labels with [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) ([`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) could also be used):

```
[~, ~, uu1 ] = unique(A(:,1)); %// get unique labels for column 1
[~, ~, uu3 ] = unique(A(:,3)); %// get unique labels for column 3
R = full(sparse(uu1, uu3, 1)); %// count repetitions of each combination
REP = R(sub2ind(size(R), uu1, uu3)); %// result as a column vector
A(:,end+1) = mat2cell(num2str(REP), ones(1,numel(REP))); %// attach result to A
```

In your example, assuming the input is

```
A = {'CM'    '00118'    '000151'    '19970303'    '19970729'    
     'RO'    '01356'    '043605'    '19970212'    '19970401'    
     'CM'    '01464'    '000151'    '19970121'    '19970218'    
     'RO'    '01356'    '043605'    '19970119'    '19970313'    
     'CM'    '00118'    '043605'    '19970114'    '19970219'    
     'CM'    '00118'    '000151'    '19970523'    '19970728'};
```

the code produces

```
REP =
     3
     2
     3
     2
     1
     3

A = 
    'CM'    '00118'    '000151'    '19970303'    '19970729'    '3'
    'RO'    '01356'    '043605'    '19970212'    '19970401'    '2'
    'CM'    '01464'    '000151'    '19970121'    '19970218'    '3'
    'RO'    '01356'    '043605'    '19970119'    '19970313'    '2'
    'CM'    '00118'    '043605'    '19970114'    '19970219'    '1'
    'CM'    '00118'    '000151'    '19970523'    '19970728'    '3'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The 2nd line of the code gives me the following error: `Error using cell/unique (line 86)
Input A must be a cell array of strings.` I guess it's because A(:,3) is a column w/ numbers only?

Comment: @user3557054 I wasn't sure which data you have in the cells of `A`. From your post it appears they are all strings (even if those strings describe numbers), and that's what I have assumed; see example in edited answer

Comment: @user3557054 If column 3 is numbers, not strings, use `[~, ~, uu3 ] = unique([A{:,3}].'); %// get unique labels`

Answer (score 1):

What if you try this:

```
    clear all
    clc

    A = cell(6,6);
    % I replicate only the relevant part of your cell array.
    A(:,1) = {'CM' 'RO' 'CM' 'RO' 'CM' 'CM'};
    A(:,3) = {'000151' '043605' '000151' '043605' '043605' '000151'}; 


    % Concatenate strings to easily compare them afterwards.
    ConcatString = cell(size(A,1),1);
    for i = 1:size(A,1)    
        ConcatString{i} = strcat(A{i,1},num2str(A{i,3}));    
    end

    REP = zeros(size(A,1),1);

   for i = 1:size(A,1)   

   Match = strcmp(ConcatString{i}, ConcatString) % Get logical array, '1' represents match.   

   NumRep = size(find(Match ==1),1) % Number of repetitions

   REP(Match ==1) = NumRep % Enter # of repetitions in REP

   end
    A(:,6) = num2cell(REP);

    disp(A)
```

which gives me this:

```
'CM'    []    '000151'    []    []    [3]
'RO'    []    '043605'    []    []    [2]
'CM'    []    '000151'    []    []    [3]
'RO'    []    '043605'    []    []    [2]
'CM'    []    '043605'    []    []    [1]
'CM'    []    '000151'    []    []    [3]
```

it's a bit crude but you can fill the blanks with your data I guess.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The code is working properly, though I still have to check if it's exactly this what I was looking for. I will let you know! Thanks :)